# Rails 4 HashWithIndifferentAccess in Application.rb breaks Rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rake

Adding this code to my Application.rb breaks the rake command and gives me the error (below) when reloading the rake tasks. I know it can find the 'social_keys.yml' because if I leave the code in and run the rails application, it finds it and authenticates to facebook just fine.

```
social_keys = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'social_keys.yml')
CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML::load(IO.read(social_keys)))[Rails.env]
CONFIG.each do |k,v|
  ENV[k.upcase] ||= v
end
```

Error:

```
Error:[rake --tasks] rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/Users/cj/RubymineProjects/MyApp/config/application.rb:26:in `<class:Application>'
/Users/cj/RubymineProjects/MyApp/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:MyApp>'
```

Here is the full code and error: 
https://gist.github.com/cdesch/11191336

I'm using the snippet code from an [example application](https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails). I suspect it has something todo with [HashWithIndifferentAccess Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14643) or this [similar reference to HashWithIndifferentAccess](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9731) although I'm not good enough with ruby to really know if they are related. From the error message I can gather that it is having a problem iterating over the hash.

How can I fix this code to work or rewrite it to perform the same functionality? The code should load the ['social_keys.yml'](https://gist.github.com/cdesch/11199213) as environment variables to use during the initialization of [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Like this:

```
 config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_KEY"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"], { :scope => 'email, offline_access', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}}
```

If this method isn't the best, Is there a different way to get my social keys in as environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that the information you have in `social_keys.yml` is not properly nested under the rails-env key.

if you do this

```
puts YAML::load(File.read(social_keys))
puts YAML::load(File.read(social_keys))[Rails.env]
```

the latter should be empty.